# Perl - why this regexp matches?

Tags: regex, perl

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(?=.*?\bPavel\b)(?=.*?\bDavid\b)((?!Petr|Jan)).*$/'
```

**input:** `Honza,David,Pavel,Marie,Adam`

I think it shouldn't pass, but it does.

The first lookahead should 'consume' `Honza,David,Pavel` and the second lookahead should fail, because there is no `David` after `Pavel`, or?

Comment: `.*?` is non-greedy. If it was `.*`, then it'd be greedy

Comment: If that's the behavior you actually desire, try something like `\bPavel(,\b.*\b)?,David\b(?!Petr|Jan)`, probably actually with a wildcard `(?!.*\b(Petr|Jan))` since they could never match adjacent to `David\b` anyway.

Comment: @MarcB: Greed or non-greed makes no difference in look-aheads, because they are *zero-width* matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The first lookahead should 'consume' `Honza,David,Pavel`.*

Not at all. It's called a *zero-width* positive lookahead because it consumes nothing. It does not advance the position at which the next atom must match, so it must match at position zero too.

---

`(?!Petr|Jan)` is not going to work as is, though. It's only checking if they're at the start of the string. You could use

```
/^(?=.*\bPavel\b)(?=.*\bDavid\b)(?!.*\b(?:Petr|Jan)\b)/x
```

which is basically a melding of

```
/\bPavel\b/ && /bDavid\b/ && !/\b(?:Petr|Jan)\b/
```

This approach only works because you are looking until the end of the string.

Comment: note that ikegami has removed the useless `.*$` that would never affect whether it matched or not

Answer (score 3):

Independent lookaheads don't "consume" anything.  That is equivalent to:

```
print if /^(?=.*?\bPavel\b)/ && /^(?=.*?\bDavid\b)/ && /^((?!Petr|Jan))/'
```

which can be simplified to just:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\bPavel\b/ && /\bDavid\b/ && /^((?!Petr|Jan))/'
```